# Second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, async-await

```
public async Task<JobViewModel> Handle(AddJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (command.JobViewModel == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty request.");
            var jobViewModel = command.JobViewModel;
          
            try
            {
                var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
                
                _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().Add(job);
                if (job.Notes!= null)
                { 
                    var newNote = job.Notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IsNew);
                    if (newNote != null)
                    {
                        newNote.JobId = job.Id;
                        _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.JobNote>().Attach(newNote);
                        _context.Entry(newNote).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                }               
                   await OnBeforeAdd(job); // job.Name = await GenerateJobName();                   
               
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                jobViewModel.Id = job.Id;
                return jobViewModel;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        
        protected  async Task OnBeforeAdd(DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job job)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(job.Name))
            {
                job.Name = await GenerateJobName();
            }
        }


private async Task<string> GenerateJobName()
        {
            Func<int, int, string> composeName = (year, number) => string.Format("S{0:D2}{1:D3}", year, number);

            int currentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year % 100;
            int newJobNumber = 501;
            //if (_context.Jobs!= null)
            // {
            // string maxJobNumber = await _context.Jobs.MaxAsync(j => j.Name);
            string maxJobNumber = await _context.Jobs.MaxAsync(j=>j.Name);
                

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(maxJobNumber))
                {
                    var matches = Regex.Matches(maxJobNumber, "S" + currentYear + "(?<num>[0-9]{3})");
                    if (matches.Count == 1)
                    {
                        newJobNumber = int.Parse(matches[0].Groups["num"].Value) + 1;
                    }
                }
           // }

            string newName = composeName(currentYear, newJobNumber);
            while (await _context.Jobs.AnyAsync(j => j.Name == newName))
            {
                newJobNumber++;
                newName = composeName(currentYear, newJobNumber);
            }
            return newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Below line give error:
string maxJobNumber = await _context.Jobs.MaxAsync(j=>j.Name);

On running the code it throws below exception "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Also the same line  "string maxJobNumber = await _context.Jobs.MaxAsync(j=>j.Name);" shows warning message as
converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type string error . Can this be an issue?

Comment: Database connections do not allow concurrent access.

Comment: @PauloMorgado What modification should be done in the code to avoid this?

Comment: The code works  fine while running locally, after deployment it is throwing this error

Comment: You can't use `_context` in more than one method chain.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments about the above code:

1. There's no need for these lines:

```
if (job.Notes!= null)
{ 
   var newNote = job.Notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IsNew);
   if (newNote != null)
   {
      newNote.JobId = job.Id;
      _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.JobNote>().Attach(newNote);
      _context.Entry(newNote).State = EntityState.Added;
   }
}
```

Once you've added the job to the DbSet, EF will automatically figure out that its JobNotes need to be added as well.  And, it will determine there state appropriately.

2. This is the pattern I would use:

```
public async Task<JobViewModel> Handle(AddJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var jobViewModel = command.JobViewModel;
   var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
   job.Name = await GenerateJobName(job.Name);
   await _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().AddAsync(job);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   jobViewModel.Id = job.Id;
   return jobViewModel;
}

private async Task<string> GenerateJobName(DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job job)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(job.Name)) return job.Name;
    ...
}
```

3. You may be overthinking all the try-catch stuff.  It is more than half the code and is obscuring the real logic.  I would move that out to a higher location and concentrate on making this do the one thing it's intended to do.
4. The reason the code performs differently in PROD is due to a race condition.  There's no debugger in PROD, so your first calls are finishing with enough time to start the second calls.